# Accessing a global variable in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

Is there a way I can access (and possibly edit) a global variable `myVar` from the Cypress side?

To be clear, by global I mean it is defined in the `document` object.
I tried through `cy.window()`

```
cy.window().then((win) => {
  console.log(Cypress.$(win.document).myVar); //undefined
  console.log(Cypress.$(win.document).get(0).myVar); //undefined
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/window.html#No-Args) here is the solution

```
it('equals bar', () => {
  let foo

  cy.window()
    .then((win) => {
      foo = win.foo
    })
    .then(() => {
      // variable "foo" has been set
      expect(foo).to.equal('bar') // test passes
    })
})
```